# Spark Categorical Data Summary Statistics

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

For continuous data, one can use `RDD.map(x => x.scores(0)).stats()` to calculate the summary statistics.

which gives result like
`org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter = (count: 4498289, mean: 0.028091, stdev: 2.332627, max: 22.713133, min: -36.627933)`

How to achieve similar result for categorical data in Spark? (count of distinct values, individual count of top values, etc)

Answer (score 1):

After further research, I found out how to get histograms of categorical data.

If anyone else is interested....

`val countColumn = parsedLines.map(_.ColumnName).countByValue()
countColumn.toSeq.sortBy(_._2).reverse.foreach(println)`

This will print each distinct values of columns and its count.